# whats happend with if(rs.next)

Tags: java, jdbc, resultset

```
try {
    setPassword(txtPassword.getText());
    setUsername(txtUserName.getText());

    MessageDigest md;

    md = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
    byte messgeDigest[] = md.digest(getPassword().getBytes());
    BigInteger number = new BigInteger(1, messgeDigest);
    String hashtext = number.toString(16);

    String qry = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username=? AND password=?";
    pst = mscon.conn().prepareStatement(qry);
    pst.setString(1, getUsername());
    pst.setString(2, hashtext);
    rs = pst.executeQuery();

    if (rs.next()) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Login Successful");
        System.out.println("Login");
    }
    else{
        System.out.println("Tri again");
    }
} catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException ex) {

} catch (SQLException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(MS_Login.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}
```

In this code the `if(rs.next)` part does not work. I tried to print some word in that block but it does not show up. Whats is problem?

Comment: Whats not working?

Comment: Ah I see, well, does the else-block work?

Comment: Perhaps your hashing algorithm does not work as expected. How do you generate the password for inserting into database?

Comment: Try `System.out.println(pst);` before the `if` and ensure this query returns row(s) from the program of your database.

Answer (score 1):

`rs.next()` attempts to retrieve the next row. If a row is returned `true` is returned, if there are no more rows `false` is returned.

Clearly, your query is not returning any rows.

Debug your program to show the values of your parameters (either by running in debug mode, or simply printing the values to stdout).

Answer (score -1):

`rs.next()` will return if there is any records present in your resultset. It is not working for you because your resutset is empty. Try debugging your and check what is the result of the query that you are executing.

Comment: Thank u!. I got this